# how to select values from 2 database

Tags: php, mysql

How can I select data in the same query from two different databases into the same server? This is what I'm doing, but my query doesn't works:
Databases: db1 and db2
details is the table in db1 database
details is the table in db2 database

Comment: $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db1";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT db1.details.name,db2.details.name FROM db1.details,db2.details where ()";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

Comment: write table with . operator like db1.table1 and db2.table1

Comment: if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["db1.details.name"]."id: " . $row["db2.details.name"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @MaheshPrasad Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you edit your question to include your code? It's easier to read if it's in a code block than if it's in the comments. (When writing or editing a question, you can put text in a code block by indenting it four spaces.)

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query as below,

```
SELECT 
    mydatabase1.tbl.*, 
    mydatabase2.tbl.*, 
FROM 
   mydatabase1.tbl, mydatabase2.tbl
```

For your information you can write the joins, where and other clauses as normal.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: i checked this one sir but not working and how to connect two database at a time

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that:

```
SELECT db1.table.*,  db2.table.*
FROM db1.table
INNER JOIN db2.table ON db1.table.detailcolumn = db2.table.detailcolumn
```

Here `db1` is the `database1`, `db2` is the `database2`

**UPDATE 1:**

In your example that you have shared in comments section, you can use as like that:

```
SELECT db1.details.name,db2.details.name 
FROM db1.details,db2.details 
WHERE db2.details.name = 'yourvalue'
AND db1.details.name = 'yourvalue'
```

Comment: please check above i written query

Comment: @MaheshPrasad: answer updated with where clause, if u want to check it just an example with both db , u can change the column as per yur need

Comment: @MaheshPrasad: did you test it?